# How to use property path in graphdb lucene connector

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, graphdb

I am creating a graphdb lucene connector having a field that traverses all reachable `locatedInside` relationships for a node and indexes the labels.

```
{
      "indexed": true,
      "stored": true,
      "multivalued": true,
      "analyzed": true,
      "fieldName": "Parentlabel",
      "propertyChain": [
        "(<http://ontologies.acme.com/core#locatedInside>+)",
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
      ],
    }
```

However no vale is indexed for this field.
It works fine if i just use one level in property chain

```
"propertyChain": [
        "http://ontologies.acme.com/core#locatedInside",
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
      ]
```

Does lucene connector in graphdb not allow using [path language](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, propertyChain of the lucene connector does not support SPARQL path expressions.

Reuse what the inferencer provides, e.g. you could either make the `http://ontologies.acme.com/core#locatedInside` transitive or if that is unfeasable due to some modelling restriction, make it a subproperty of a transitive property and use that within the properyChain definition of the field instead.